# Links to files inside PHP/HTML code subject to .htaccess mod_rewrite too?

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, redirect

Just wanted to make sure:

When I write:

```
require('/path/to/file/file.php');
```

Is the file required with respect to Apache's mod_rewrite? (which seems unreasonable, since it should be there for user URL redirection)
What I mean is, that if .htaccess sends all requests to "index.php", index.php would be required instead?

**And**

When inside HTML markup, should paths to files e.g. images, links, css be written with respect to .htaccess mod_rewrite?

Say this is the public root: `http://example.com/`
The image is located in `'/img/image.png'`
`RewriteRule` sends all requests with anything after the url end trailing slash to `http://example.com/`
Does this mean the image would not be found?

I suppose this applies to JS/CSS files as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the file required with respect to apache's mod_rewrite?

No. Never. Except if you prepend the path with a `http://`, in which case the HTTP wrapper will come into play and make a normal web request.

> When inside HTML markup, should paths to files e.g. images, links, css be written with respect to htaccess mod_rewrite?

Absolutely. I don't understand your example but any URL you use in a HTML file will be requested by *the client's browser* and be subject to whatever mod_rewrite rules you have set up. The same goes for Javascript, CSS files and the like.

Comment: Yes, your example is what I meant (I probably didn't articulate it properly). I thought so regarding the php, just wasn't very sure about the html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First questions: No, `mod_rewrite` has no influence on the path you specify in `require()`.
Second question: Yes, it would not be found. But you can put a [rewrite condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) before your rewrite rule to circumvent this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

With this, the rewrite rule is only applied, if the requested file does not exist.